# What is the static type of `this` in Java 8 default interfaces?

Tags: java, java-8

I'm implementing the visitor pattern for a project and realized I may be able to save some typing by having the default implementation of accept be the following.

```
public interface Visitable {
    default public void accept(Visitor v) {
        v.visit(this);
    }
}
```

However if the static type of `this` resolves to Visitable this implementation will not work so what is the static type of `this` in this situation?

Comment: What do you reckon it should be?

Comment: Have you tried it and seen what happens?

Comment: What is your definition of `Visitor`?

Comment: Ha! Wouldn't that be nice if it works :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since, in your context, `this` is used as a parameter type, the call will be resolved to `Visitor#visit(Visitable)` at compile- and runtime. Thus, you gain nothing from trying to make a default method in this scenario.

The only time `this` can be used polymorphically is when using it as the receiver:

```
public interface Foo
{
    public default void bar()
    {
         this.bar(1);
    }

    public void bar(int i);
}
```

Comment: I created a small example to test this and the type did indeed end up being `Visitable`. I had to override the `accept` method in each implementing class to get the behaviour I wanted even though the implementation for each class was the same as the default. I was hoping that Java would essentially do a copy paste of the default method into each implementing class but this is not the case.

Comment: Indeed this is not the case, because it would mean that you couldn't use default methods in subclasses that were compiled before the method was added - which was why default methods were added in the first place.

Comment: @Clashsoft `The only time this can be used polymorphically is when using it as the receiver:` But even then all you get is the standard dynamic dispatch of Java, you can't refer to any method that isn't defined by `Object`, the current interface or any of its superinterfaces. So the compile type of `this` is always the current class, as indeed it is everywhere else too.

Comment: @en4bz When you think about it, the whole point of the visitor pattern is to overcome Java's lack of dispatching between overloaded functions based on the runtime type of arguments. If the `default` method behaved like you wanted it to, that would essentially make the visitor pattern unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

You can figure this out by experiment:

```
public interface Visitable {
    default public void accept(Visitor v) {
        v.visit(this);
    }
}

public class Vis1 implements Visitable {

}

public class Visitor {
    public void visit(Visitable v) {
        System.out.println("Am visiting a generic Visitable");
    }

    public void visit(Vis1 v) {
        System.out.println("Am visiting a Vis1");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Visitor v = new Visitor();
        Vis1 v1 = new Vis1();
        v1.accept(v);
    }
}
```

The above outputs `Am visiting a generic Visitable`